# Thread not starting after Thread Sleeep

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

In this i am using stopwatch. when stop watch value between 0 to 15 it will play video on screen 1 and after 15 it will display on screen 0 but thread is not starting after `Thread.sleep()`

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    int[] screentimings = new int[2] { 20, 20 };
    Stopwatch sp;
    Thread thread1;
    //private System.Timers.Timer _timer = new System.Timers.Timer();

    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        thread1 = new Thread(new ThreadStart(A));
       thread1.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        sp = new Stopwatch();
        sp.Start();
        thread1.Start();          
    }
       [STAThread]
    public void showOnMonitor(int showOnMonitor) 
    { 
        Screen[] sc; 
        sc = Screen.AllScreens; 
        Form1 f = new Form1(); 
        f.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; 
        f.Left = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Left; 
        f.Top = sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Top;
        f.Height=sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Height;
        f.Width=sc[showOnMonitor].Bounds.Width;
        f.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual; 
        f.ShowDialog(); 
    }

    [STAThread]
    private void A()
    {
        long i = sp.Elapsed.Seconds;
        if (i > 0 && i < 15)
        {
            showOnMonitor(1);
        }
        else
        {
            showOnMonitor(0);
        }
        Thread.Sleep(500);
    }
}
```

showOnMonitor(1) code is executed but after 15 seconds showOnMonitor(0) is not working. 
 I am new with thread don't know whats wrong with it. It might be because of `[STAThread]` without this it giving Single Thread Exception.

Comment: Your void A doesn't have any looping, so it executes once and the thread ends.

Comment: I am new with thread question can be foolish. I think void A() is called again and again by thread.

Comment: If you want to call something again and again, You need to use `Timer`.

Comment: Even the code in the thread did loop, which it doesn't as you've written it, it wouldn't because `ShowDialog` is a blocking call - it would suspend the thread's loop until you closed your new `Form1`

Comment: @SriramSakthivel in timer i am not able to get its current value that's why i choose stop watch and thread.

Comment: @J... then what should i do in this scenario.

Comment: What you expect to do after 15 sec. You want to close the first form and show second? Or You want to show both? Or you just want to move the first form to second monitor? Also update which version of .Net you're using.

Comment: @HotCoolStud I don't know.  It's not clear what you are trying to do or why.  If the ***only*** purpose here is to make a form move to second screen 15 seconds after showing it then you absolutely do not need a thread at all.  Use a timer and be done with it - use the spare time to go back to MSDN and study threads some more...

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i want to show both but on different monitors, with time only video content will change and i am using 4.5 framework. 'thank you for your support

Answer (score 2):

You don't need a thread at all. Threads are used to do more than one action concurrently. Explaining it will be out of scope of this question. Please read more about threads [here](http://www.albahari.com/threading/).

Since you're in .Net 4.5 you can use async/await to accomplish your goal *very easily*.

```
public partial class Form2 : Form
{
    public Form2()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    protected async override void OnLoad(EventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnLoad(e);
        await ShowForms();//Show the forms
    }

    private async Task ShowForms()
    {
        ShowOnMonitor(1);
        await Task.Delay(15000);//15 seconds, adjust it for your needs.
        ShowOnMonitor(2);
    }

    private void ShowOnMonitor(int showOnMonitor)
    {
        Screen[] allScreens = Screen.AllScreens;
        Rectangle screenBounds = allScreens[showOnMonitor - 1].Bounds;
        Form1 f = new Form1
        {
            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None,
            Left = screenBounds.Left,
            Top = screenBounds.Top,
            Height = screenBounds.Height,
            Width = screenBounds.Width,
            StartPosition = FormStartPosition.Manual
        };
        f.Show();//Use show, not ShowDialog.
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `async void` and not `async Task`? `ShowForms` isn't an event handler. You should also `await` inside `OnLoad`, so any exception propagated from `ShowForms` wont go unhandled.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov No reason, It just happened. Updated my answer, Thanks.

Comment: @SriramSakthivel i think it will call ShowForms() only once but want it to regularly call ShowForms() after each 3 seconds.I tried using System.Timer but as it runs on multiple threads and now i have to call all the process by single thread because i am using windows media player for playing video and on multiple thread it throws cross thread exception

Comment: @HotCoolStud Use `System.Windows.Forms.Timer` everything will be ok.